# How to get the stack trace when installing an app with adb install?

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to view the stacktrace (as you get when you install via the marketplace) when you install an app via adb install command?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the environment variable ADB_TRACE to the value 'all'.
For Linux it is this command:

```
export ADB_TRACE=all
```

The traces from the ADB front-end will be shown on the screen, and the traces from the server will be saved in /tmp/adb.log.